# Routing between different subnets with Hyper-V adapter

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, routing, hyper-v, subnet

I have a Hyper-V server set up. I want to keep my virtual machines on a different subnet but give them internet connection and be able to access them from my main network.

My host machine only has a single network adapter and using an external switch isn't a good option as it seems very unstable and sometimes prevents my server from connecting to my network correctly.

**I have tried the following:**

The host machine's current network settings look like this: (IP, Mask, Gateway)

```
Main Network Adapter                192.168.1.109  MASK 255.255.255.0  192.168.1.1
Hyper-V Internal Network Adapter    192.168.10.1   MASK 255.255.0.0    192.168.1.1
```

To connect the Hyper-V network to the internet I tried a RRAS setup to use a NAT connection to my normal network, and also using ICS to share my main adapter's connection to the Hyper-V adapter. In neither of these cases could the VMs reach my router.

I have tried a large combination of static routes on the VMs, my host machine, the router and other computers on my main network. None of these have worked. With the RRAS setup I could in some cases ping from my main network to the VM, but not the other way.

I would be very grateful if anyone knew of a way I could correctly configure this!

EDIT: Following network diagram of current setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I believe you need to set up the network and routes in your router as that is what is responsible for routing you from one subnet to the other and from your private network(s) to the Internet.

If you are using a basic consumer grade router, many of these cannot handle multiple lan subnets afaik, so bear that in mind.

Comment: I've already tried doing the routing from my router using static routes, setting them up across the LAN interface on different subnets. This didn't work, and I'm pretty sure because the Hyper-V adapter on the host machine isn't connected directly to my router.

Comment: Whether the hyper-v adapter is connected directly to your gateway router's ports should not matter unless there is another layer 3 device (L3 switch or router) between them (which I don't see in your diagram). 
I'm not familiar with that router so don't know it's capabilities but it is the gateway router's job to route traffic between L3 networks so the route should be set up there.  Then you need to ensure that traffic from your VMs is making it to the gateway (I'm assuming all .10.x are VMs, yes?)  Check your route tables and arp tables on the vms to see what routes they are aware of.

Comment: The .10 subnet machines are all VMs. They are able to ping the router and have internet access so I assume traffic from the VMs is all correct. However none of the .1 subnet machines (PC01) can ping the VMs, so I believe my router isn't routing traffic to the .10 gateway correctly, or there is something I am missing at the virtual switch.

Comment: If he .10 subnet can ping .1 but .1 cannot ping .10 then your router either has no route (does not know how to find the .10 subnet) or ingress traffic is being filtered somewhere. Base don diagram RRAS or firewall of hypervisor server.

Comment: Okay - I'm guessing my router can't find the .10 subnet, probably because my network adapter isn't physically connected to the network - it's the virtual Hyper-V one. Do you know how I could set up a route in my router and/or configure the RRAS role on the server so that the .10 subnet is picked up by my router correctly?

Comment: I'd say you need to **verify** if your router is aware of the .10 subnet before you start poking about in RRAS.  Because if the router isn't routing the .10, RRAS will never see the traffic.  Once you know for certain the traffic is getting as far as rras then you can start working out why it might not be getting through.
As far as configuring that router, sorry. I have zero familiarity with it.  I'm sure Google can help.

Comment: How can I go about verifying it? I know the VMs on the .10 subnet are able to ping the router, so it must be replying and sending packets back. I know how to configure the router with static routes across the LAN interface, however I am not sure exactly what static route I need to put in place. I have tried 192.168.10.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.109 but had no luck.

Comment: If you can add a route you should be able to also see the routing table on the router.  You should see both directions.  As far as your example for adding the route (if I'm intuiting the syntax correctly) the last parameter should be to the .1 subnet - ergo 192.168.1.0/24 or however you express that in that router (/24 is CIDR Notation and is equiv. to a 255.255.255.0 mask).  You can also try to trace route from one machine to the other.  Where it dies might clue you.  You can also try maybe to simplify..  Two machines (phys), static IPs, one in .10, one in .1, connected directly to the router

Comment: And see if you can get it routing between the two, then add more variables in from there.  Sorry I can't help more.  This is my frustration with consumer grade routers.  On something real you could have seen/verified this in two seconds and added/fixed it in 4.

Comment: I'll just have to do a lot of troubleshooting until I (hopefully) get it working. However as far as I can see, my router doesn't have a routing table (or one that can be found easily). I'll have to try and work things out using another method. You have been a massive help to me- thank you ever so much!

Comment: You're welcomed.  Glad I could be of some help.  It's a difficult thing when you run into the limits of consumer-grade hardware.  The stuff can carry you to a point but once you crest the horizon there's often little to nowhere left to go.  You can try process of elimination based on the info I've given.  Another 'maybe' is if your router offers it or you  can find a way to get ssh access you may be able to inspect the routing tables at the command line.  Most of these are linux based so you might luck out.

Good Luck.